# Python corrupted

Tags: python

Please could you help me with an issue that I have been battling with for a long time.

In the top right corner there is a red circle with a minus sign. The error says "a problem occurred when checking for the update".

As a result, I am unable to launch terminal (even with Ctrl-alt-T) so I am unable to run any commands to attempt to fix it. I assume that the issue came from corrupting python as that I was attempting to upgrade it when the issue started. I am running Ubunutu 18.04 LTS.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with the following details: Do you get any notifications about a problem? Does the circle give any more information? (on hover or click, don't remember which) What happens when you try to open a terminal?

Comment: Did you try `CTRL + ALT + T` to open terminal ?

Comment: I've now included the requested information above on the information provide in the error and that I have tried that shortcut with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I one time updated python to be primarily running 3.9 and I can't open the terminal. I had to change the version back to an older version. If you have vscode you can use its terminal to reinstall python